# Bash: Populate Array with read from for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, select

In one of my classes, I've been assigned a problem set. On one of the exercises, I have to use a for loop and the read command to take in three strings, then use select option in (...) on my array. Below is my code, but I simply can't seem to properly populate the array using the for loop. I've already figured out a few alternatives, but I must use this general structure.

```
echo Please type in 3 foods you like:
for xx in `seq 1 3`; do
    read -p "enter food $xx " array[$xx]
    echo $array
done

PS3='Now Select the food you like the best: '
select option in array
do
    echo "The option you have selected is: $option"
    break
done
```

Answer (score 3):

The array is populated correctly; you just aren't *expanding* it correctly.

```
# Don't use seq; just use bash's C-style for loop.
# The only reason to avoid this kind of loop is
# to make your shell script POSIX-compatible, but
# seq isn't part of the POSIX standard either.
  for ((xx=1; xx<=3; xx++)); do   # Don't use seq
    read -p "Enter foo $xx" array[xx]
    echo "${array[@]}"
done

PS3='Now Select the food you like the best: '
select option in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "The option you have selected is: $option"
    break
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had managed to figure out the reading in, but I was still stuck on the echo part. Thanks!